# SQL deleting one of two duplicate records?

Tags: sql

I have a DB that has a problem that there are two of the same records for everything but they all have a different ID, but they have 2 columns (the actual data) that are the same. I was wondering if there was a good way to have a DELETE statement where I could select all these records that have the 2 columns match but have a different ID and delete one (doesn't matter which one)?

If you could could you give me a code example?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you put any thought or effort into this yet? If you don't understand why this is bad, please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

```
Delete from ... 
where id in (select max(id), count as c 
             from ... 
             group by data1, data2 
             having c >1)
```

The idea is to select the bigger id of all duplicate rows, by grouping the rows on the column that are the same and making sure that there are multiple rows (having clause).

Comment: MIN() can also be used; however, the added explanation helps. For some added explanation, MIN()/MAX() just results in "It doesn't matter what the value is as long as it's different from others." But be aware that `id` does need to be unique in order to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from your_table
where id not in
(
  select min(id)
  from your_table
  group by col2
)
```